# Formatting Code in Chat

Tags: discussion, chat, markdown

I know that I can format `code inline` in both questions, and comments on SO. But this formatting with backticks, does not seem to work in chat.

Is there a reason for this? Also, is there a way to format code in chatting ?

Comment: Note that chat MarkDown only works for single line messages. If you insert a linebreak, all markdown is rendered literally.

Comment: @ManishEarth I find that it's a little erratic, sometimes it works, generally it doesn't. But more to the point, in a forum designed for discussing code, it's annoying that you can't accurately render code in the chat areas!

Comment: @robert markdown may not work, but you can always codeformat multiline messeges by clickibg the fixedwidth button. And backticks work normally in singleline messages. Btw, by multiline, I mean a message with an explicit line break, not a mesage that has wrapped.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found [these tools](https://stackapps.com/questions/3161/chat-easy-input-tools-provides-keyboard-shortcuts-for-common-text-formatting-c) to be incredibly helpful in formatting my chat messages.