# How do I post code in chat?

Tags: support, chat, code-formatting

I would like to be able to post code in chat. I know that I can post inline snippets of code by using backticks, but I don't know how to post blocks of code, with the entire chat message formatted as code, and indentation respected. I am aware of [Formatting Code in Chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139885/formatting-code-in-chat). After reading the comments, I found out that I could format in "fixed width", but I can't see a "fixed width" button anywhere. What should I do?

Comment: You need at least 2 lines for the "fixed width" button to appear.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> autoformats your selection as code in chat. Additionally, if you have two lines or more, a "fixed width" button will appear.